# When can methods in UrlHelperExtensions return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nullable-reference-types, asp.net-core-7.0

I use the `Url.Page` methods from [`UrlHelperExtensions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/610fe433e07b32ed451ed99d07df63be47c29050/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/UrlHelperExtensions.cs). They return `string?`, which trigger analysers in my code.

When can those methods return null? The class docs do not say.

Comment: The same problem exists for the other methods: `Action`, `ActionLink`, `Page`, `PageLink`, `RouteUrl`.

Comment: I've also mentioned this on [the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54465) with the hope they'll update the class docs. Please upvote that issue if it affects you.

Comment: [`UrlHelperExtensions.Page()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/610fe433e07b32ed451ed99d07df63be47c29050/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/UrlHelperExtensions.cs#L509) returns null when `IUrlHelper.RouteUrl()` returns null. `IUrlHelper` is an interface, but `UrlHelper.RouteUrl()` returns null when `UrlHelperBase.GenerateUrl()` returns null, which happens when the `string? virtualPath` is null, which can happen when [`Router.GetVirtualPath(context)`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/610fe433e07b32ed451ed99d07df63be47c29050/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/UrlHelper.cs#L93C16-L93C46) is null.

Comment: Now `Router` is just an [`IRouter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.irouter?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which is implemented by many classes including e.g. `RouteBase`. If you check its [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/610fe433e07b32ed451ed99d07df63be47c29050/src/Http/Routing/src/RouteBase.cs#L150C37) you will see its implementation of `GetVirtualPath()` returns null in various situations.  And that's as far as I got.